# Protractor - get browser title as string

Tags: string, testing, protractor

I'd like to store initial device title, which is accessible via GUI in browser as page title, and reuse it later in the code. E.g. I want to change name of device if it is set to some particular name only, and to store an old device name in browser console log. Code might look like this:

```
    var some_name = 'Some Name';
    var title = browser.getTitle();
    console.log(title);
    if (title.equals('Some Name')){
    some_name = 'Some Other Name';
    }
    setDeviceName(some_name);
```

unfortunately, to that protractor responds with

```
    TypeError: title.equals is not a function
```

How is it possible to extract browser title as string?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everyone, the solution due to igniteram1 is

```
    var some_name = 'Some Name';
    some_name = browser.getTitle().then(function(webpagetitle){
      if (webpagetitle === 'Some Name'){
        return 'Some Other Name';
      }else{
        return 'Some Name'
      } 
    });
    expect(some_name).toEqual('Some Other Name');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to @Sudharshan Selvraj's answer,its good practice to use strict equality `===` instead of `==` and to `return` the value.

```
var some_name = 'Some Name';
some_name = browser.getTitle().then(function(webpagetitle){
  if (webpagetitle === 'Some Name'){
    return 'Some Other Name';
  }else{
    return 'Some Name';
  }
 });
expect(some_name).toEqual('Some Other Name');
```

Comment: Thanks! We really need a return here, I guess because it's a variable, not an object. With small modification - putting `some_name=` before `browser.getTitle()......` it worked!
`

Answer (score 6):

If you aware of the new asyc/await you may use:

`expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual("myCustomTitle");`

Answer (score 3):

In protractor whatever information you need from browser will be a promise and not a string. in order to fetch the value you need to resolve the promise. look at the below example.

```
 var title = browser.getTitle();
 title.then(function(webpagetitle){
    if (webpagetitle == 'Some Name'){
      some_name = 'Some Other Name';
    }
})
```

Comment: Also I highly recommend to move such pre-configurations in configuration file of protractor. Any manipulation a with variables inside Promises will not be properly displayed in other sync functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but the response to this code is
    
    TypeError: webpagetitle.equals is not a function

Comment: @user3036878 equals is not a valid javascript method. instead use "==" to compare values.

Comment: When I use ==, some_name variable is not getting new value - it means, comparison didn't work.

Comment: try to debug the code using console.log() and verify whether you are getting correct title from the webpage.

Comment: I am not getting correct title with this code. webpagetitle is 'undefined', though page title is not.

Comment: `browser.getTitle().then(function(webpagetitle) { console.log(webpagetitle); });`

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj can i have you Skype id or contact number? mine is 'sallojusuresh'

Comment: I have sent you request in skype.

Answer (score 0):

***.equals()*** is not a function in *JavaScript*, but it's a valid function in *Java*. In Java Script, we have **'==', '==='** as an alternative for performing equal operations.

var x=10

**==**  compare only *values of operands*, not type of operands

example:

x==10  =>   true

x=="10" =>  true

**===**  compare both *values and type of operands*

example:

x===10  =>   true

x==="10" =>  false(type of x in int and "10" is string)

```
  var someName;
  browser.getTitle().then(function (webPageTitle) {
    if (webPageTitle == 'Some Name'){
        someName= 'Some Other Name';
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple function in protractor to get the title when in the promise it shows the title properly, but when I do console.log it gives :

Title Got is ManagedPromise::123 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
it('should have a title', function(one) {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  browser.get('https://tasyah.com');

  titleGot = browser.getTitle().then(function(promisedResult){
      console.log("Title is : " + promisedResult);
      return promisedResult;

  })
  console.log("Title Got is " + titleGot);
  expect(titleGot).toEqual('Tasyah: Online Shopping For Fashion And Costume Jewellery');
  console.log("Title Got is " + titleGot);

});
```

});

Any explanation on this is appreciated...

Thanks 
Naveen

Comment: `browser.getTitle()` returns a promise. `browser.getTitle().then(...)` also returns a promise, which is assigned to `titleGot`. `titleGot` does not get the result of the promise. As stated in protractor docs, `expect` is patched to process promises, so `expect(...).toEqual(...)` evaluates the _result_ of the promise. In contrast, your `console.log` commands are executed synchronuously and do not care whether the input is a promise or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Page Object .po file**

```
  getTableRows() {
    return element.all(by.css('[data-qa="qa-table"] tr'));
  }
```

**.e2e.spec file**

```
<PROMISE-APPROCH>

obj.getTableRows().then((list)=> {
  list.count().then((totalRows)=>{
    expect(totalRows).toBe(10); // example 
  })
});


<ASYNC-AWAIT-APPROCH>

const rowsCount = await obj.getTableRows().count();
expect(rowsCount).toBe(10); // example
```